# get contents of the request object in socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am new to socket.io and I try to tell apart every client that connects to my node server.

I want to send data to just one client, not broadcast the same data to all of them. So, I have to find a unique piece of each client.

If I got it, I have to do something like

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var origin =  socket.request;
    console.log("hey, so , new ws connection is >  "+origin);
});
```

but I get `[object, Object]`.

What are the contents of this object, so I can get something unique like an id. Also what other data this object contains that may come handy in the future?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I saw the socket.id. But, everytime I refresh, the id changes. I want something to be stable, otherwise if the client refreshes for some reason, will no longer be related with the first id. Any tips?

Comment: So did you find answer to explore the contents of the request object? Are the form text fields populated as object fields? or do we need a body-parser?

Answer (score 1):

every connect have `socket.id` is unique, if you use socket-io adapter you can use socket handshake info. on Browser for geting socket.id try

```
 $(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#socketId").val(socket.id);
        },100);
    });
```

if console.log you will see socket.id in future

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the socket.id property to get hold of the unique identifier for the socket (client socket).
As for other data this object contains, there are plenty that are useful, but the usefulness is dependant on the application. Have a look at the following link for available properties/methods on the socket object. http://socket.io/docs/server-api/

Some very useful methods are emit, join, leave, to, in and properties include id and rooms.

Comment: I saw the `socket.id`. But, everytime I refresh, the id changes. I want something to be stable, otherwise if the client refreshes for some reason, will no longer be related with the first id. Any tips?